# AngularJs AngularUI Sortable model link to specific field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to bind the angularJS ui-sortable to a specific value in the model,  list : field.sort_order to be exact.

But cant seem to get it working, the sortable js code is working and moves the objects around in the model but wont update that specific value, basically I don't know how to pass it the specific field to update/read, is this possible?

I have the following scripts for angularJS running:

```
'//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.js'
'//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui.min.js'  


  <tbody ui-sortable ng-model="list">
        <tr ng-repeat="(key, field) in list">
            <td><img src="/images/defaults/updown_ico_small.png"></td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="field.field_name" /></td>
            <td>
                <select ng-if="..." ng-model="..." ng-options="..."></select>
                <select ng-if="..." ng-model="..." ng-options="..."></select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button ng-click="...">Delete</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

This is the output from this snippet

[image]

Array example:

```
1 => 
    array
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'download_type' => string 'custom' (length=6)
      'download_ext' => string 'csv' (length=3)
      'project_id' => string '157' (length=3)
      'DownloadField' =>   // this is what i call 'list' in the example
        array
          0 => 
            array
              'id' => string '18' (length=2)
              'field_reference' => string 'FALSE' (length=5)
              'field_name' => string 'Delete flag' (length=11)
              'sort_order' => string '0' (length=1)
          1 => 
            array
              'id' => string '19' (length=2)
              'field_reference' => string 'CUSTOM_RESULT_QUESTION' (length=22)
              'field_name' => string 'Category ID' (length=11)
              'sort_order' => string '1' (length=1)
          2 => 
            array
              'id' => string '20' (length=2)
              'field_reference' => string 'CUSTOM_RESULT_ANSWER' (length=20)
              'field_name' => string 'Category Value' (length=14)
              'sort_order' => string '2' (length=1)
          3 => 
            array
              'id' => string '21' (length=2)
              'field_reference' => string 'company_alt_name' (length=16)
              'field_name' => string 'Exhibitor ID' (length=12)
              'sort_order' => string '3' (length=1)
 2 =>
```

2 will contain a similar set of data.

Comment: Is `list` an object or an array?

Comment: It's a associative array (passed in from php)

Comment: http://codepen.io/thgreasi/pen/iKEHd maybe add sortableOptions

Comment: I've been looking at that but im not entirely sure how to pass the data i want into any of the functions.  'list' is an array of an array so i need to pass both indexes.. but im unsure how to pass any data to the ui-sortable directive? Still quite new the angularjs :S

Comment: Since `list` is an array, the syntax for looping over it should be `ng-repeat="item in list"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I stopped trying to see how I could get data passed into the stop method, I realised I had all the information I needed to update the sort_order variable.
The sortable was working in so much as it reordered the array, using that information I did:

```
stop: function(e, ui) {
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.formData.length; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < $scope.formData[i]['DownloadField'].length; j++){
            $scope.formData[i]['DownloadField'][j]['sort_order'] = j;
        }
    }
}
```

It may not be the lightest approach and I will probably add some checks for updates/new data etc. but it works.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript objects (they're different from associative arrays, but kind of look like them) are not ordered so ui-sortable cannot be used to re-order them. You have to use an array. You could, for example, convert your object into an array of pairs.

Comment: "Array.isArray($scope.formData)" returns true, which is the root data for this example.   Does that not mean it is an array?

Comment: Also, in my code, it happily moves the row in the array up and down with the sortable controls.  But I want it to change the field 'sort_order' inside that row.   Which I was hoping there to be something for?

Comment: `formData`? In your code, the variable you give to the ng-model of ui-sortable is `list`. Are they the same thing?

Comment: Ive updated my question with a representation of the array in php. This is essentially formData

Comment: It looks like an array, yes. Consider this answer obselete. :)

Answer (score 1):

Pass a configuration object to the `ui-sortable` directive, with a handler function for the `stop` event.

View

```
<tbody ui-sortable="sortableOptions" ng-model="list">
```

Controller

```
$scope.sortableOptions = {
    stop: function (event, ui) {}
};
```

The second parameter of the handler contains what you need:

- `ui.item.sortable.index` is the index where the dragged item was before it was dragged
- `ui.item.sortable.dropindex` is the index where the dragged item was dropped

From there you can loop through all the items which index was changed and update them.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3m6a33u9/1/)

Comment: Away from the workstation atm, but this looks promising. Will give a go later today get back to you :)

Comment: This is really close to working, but im again stuck at the fact the data i need to loop is nested inside another parent.  I need to pass the parent index too but am unsure how to pass custom information.